# Java array initialization

Tags: java

What happens when we print reference variable of array initialization?

```
int[] it=new int[10];  
sop(it);
```

What is the result?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: An array is an Object too.

Comment: I think sop() is some kind of 'System.out.prinln()'

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] it = new int[10];  
System.out.println(it);
```

`it` is an object, hence you are calling [`println(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) of [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) (`System.out`), which calls `toString()` on the passed object internally. The arrays' `toString()` is similar to [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)'s [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

```
getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
```

So the output would be something like:

```
[I@756a7c99
```

where `[` represnts the depth of the array, and `I` refers to `int`. `756a7c99` is the value returned from [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) as a hex number.

Read [`Class.getName()` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29).

---

To print an array, use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29), something like:

```
int[] it = new int[10];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(it));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `sop` is `System.out.println`, it will show you a String resulting returned by the `toString` method. In this case it will be the name of the class + "@" + the hexa of the hashcode.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `[I@30c221`

It's the memory address of your new array

```
    int[] it=new int[10];
    System.out.println(it);
```