# java split sentences into words

Tags: java

How to split an `array` of sentences into an `array of array` of words?
If i can split the sentence using `split()` ..but it's used only single array.
but I need to do multiple array..

Eg:

```
sentences[0]="one sentence"
sentences[1]=" one sen...."
```

I need to split like this...

```
word[0][0]="one word" //first row first word
word[0][1]="second word"
word[0][2]="third word"
word[1][0]="..."//second row first word**
```

any one can help me.

Comment: `split()` is a method of `String` which ... you have an array of.

Comment: Behold the [for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) !

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this..

```
for(i=0;i<someLength;i++){
word[i] = sentence[i].split("yourDelimiter");
}
```

Comment: how can i  split one dimensional[] of sentences into two dimensional[][] of words...

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] sentences = ...
String[][] words = new String[sentences.length][];

for(int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++)
{
    words[i] = sentences[i].split("\\s+");
}
```

Comment: hi friend ...it'll be show this [[Ljava.lang.String;@1507fb2...but not print correct word.

Comment: @user2010228 how are you printing the results ?

Comment: @user2010228 See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14717835/597657